# How do I select a record from one table in a mySQL database, based on the existence of data in a second?

Tags: mysql, syntax

Please forgive my ignorance here. SQL is decidedly one of the biggest "gaps" in my education that I'm working on correcting, come October. Here's the scenario:

I have two tables in a DB that I need to access certain data from. One is `users`, and the other is `conversation_log`. The basic structure is outlined below:

**users:**

- id (INT)
- name (TXT)

**conversation_log**

- userid (INT) // same value as id in users - actually the only field in this table I want to check
- input (TXT)
- response (TXT)

(note that I'm only listing the structure for the fields that are {or could be} relevant to the current challenge)

What I want to do is return a list of names from the users table that have at least one record in the conversation_log table. Currently, I'm doing this with two separate SQL statements, with the one that checks for records in conversation_log being called hundreds, if not thousands of times, once for each userid, just to see if records exist for that id.

Currently, the two SQL statements are as follows:

select `id` from `users` where 1; (gets the list of userid values for the next query)

select `id` from `conversation_log` where `userid` = $userId limit 1; (checks for existing records)

Right now I have 4,000+ users listed in the users table. I'm sure that you can imagine just how long this method takes. I **know** there's an easier, more efficient way to do this, but being self-taught, this is something that I have yet to learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do what is called a 'Join'.  This, um, joins the rows of two tables together based on values they have in common.

See if this makes sense to you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.name
FROM users JOIN conversation_log ON users.id = converation_log.userid
```

Now JOIN by itself is an "inner join", which means that it will only return rows that both tables have in common.  In other words, if a specific conversation_log.userid doesn't exist, it won't return any part of the row, user or conversation log, for that userid.

Also, +1 for having a clearly worded question : )

EDIT: I added a "DISTINCT", which means to filter out all of the duplicates.  If a user appeared in more than one conversation_log row, and you didn't have DISTINCT, you would get the user's name more than once.  This is because JOIN does a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), or does every possible combination of rows from each table that match your JOIN ON criteria.

Comment: Where do you address the "having at least one conversation log" requirement without returning multiple records for users with multiple conversation logs?

Comment: If you're doing an inner join, and there are no conversation_logs that match the join predicate (having a certain user id), the user with that id won't show up.

Comment: True, but if there are multiple logs you get multiple records.

Comment: That's what the DISTINCT was supposed to take into account.

Comment: This method worked well enough to get a result, and I'm sure that I can "tweak" it from here. My thanks to everyone who answered/commented. I've learned a little here, and now have something I can study, to gain more understanding. :)

Comment: I should have probably pointed out that, on the users table, id is unique, and the table's key.

Comment: Well, I've implemented this method, and it's simply amazing, not only how much it's improved performance of my script, but also in how much code I was able to remove to get the same results. YAY!!! Again, my thanks, Dave!

Comment: @DaveMorton no problem!  Also, nice name you have there : )

Comment: @DaveMorton It always amazes me how essentially equivalent answers can get wildly different scores on StackOverflow. Did you even bother trying my answer? Or ontangent'a for that matter?

Comment: @Branko: Indeed I did, and all of them worked, yet Dave's needed the least amount of "tweaking" to get it to do just what I wanted. Please note that I **did** give thanks above to everyone who submitted a solution. Honest, it's not my intention that anyone should feel slighted. :)

Comment: @DaveMorton I have no problem you picking Dave's answer over mine - this is a good answer and if you feel it fits your need the best that's perfectly fine. What I have problem with is that essentially good answers ended up scored 0 and even -1! My small criticism goes to you for not upvoting the answers that, in your own words, "work". My big criticism goes to the StachOverflow community at large that tends to just read the first answer and not bother with the rest. So whoever gets upvoted first, gets to be upvoted later and helpful answers tend to be ignored purely on timing.

Comment: @Branko:  In all honesty, I didn't realize that one could "up-vote" more than one answer. In fact, I figured that it was the same as when I picked the one answer that was "best". Knowing now what I do, I'll address the issue. Sorry, but I'm still a newbie here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM conversation_log
    WHERE users.id = conversation_log.userid
)
```

In plain English: select every row from `users`, such that there is at least one row from `conversation_log` with the matching `userid`.

Comment: Works but a join would be shorter and possibly better depending on the optimizer.

Comment: @JimGarrison JOIN would give you multiple "copies" or a row from `users` where there are multiple corresponding rows from `conversation_log`. To remedy that, you'd need to employ `GROUP BY`, but by that time your query would already be more complex that what I proposed. As for performance, a "serious" DBMS should have no problems optimizing either way, I'm not sure about MySQL though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to read is JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT count(*), users.name 
FROM users  left join conversion_log  on users.id = conversation_log.userid
Group by users.name
```

You could add at the end if you wanted
    HAVING count(*) > 0

Comment: You need just JOIN (not LEFT JOIN) here. Also you meant `GROUP BY users.name` instead of `Group by users.id`, right?